# How do I find the gradients of an X -> RELU -> RELU -> Softmax network?

Tags: gradient-descent

I am trying to use the MNIST digits dataset with logistic regression. I am only using numpy as I would like to implement a simple project myself before using something like pytorch.

My network topology is an input layer with 784 input features (rows) by 10,000 columns (training examples), this goes to a 3 node RELU layer, then another 3 node RELU layer and then a 10 node softmax layer for output.

So X->RELU->RELU->Softmax
I know the cost function is `J = -SUM(y_i * ln(y_hat_i))`

I can find the derivative of `J` with respect to `y_hat`.

`dJ/dy_hat = y_hat_i - y_i`

but going back any further than that I run into a wall
how do I find `dJ/dW3`, `dJ/dW2`, `dJ/dW1` and `dJ/db3`, `dJ/db2`, `dJ/db1`?